# Visual understanding for the non-injectivity of $h(x_1,x_2) = (x_1^2+2x_1x_2+x_2^2, 2x_1+2x_2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $h(x_1,x_2) = (x_1^2+2x_1x_2+x_2^2, 2x_1+2x_2).$ Determine if $h$ is locally injective.

I know the function is not locally injective. Factoring one has $h(x_1,x_2) = ((x_1+x_2)^2, 2(x_1+x_2))$ from where it can be seen. However, I was trying to get some visual understanding of this and letting $x=(x_1+x_2)^2$ and $y=2x_1+2x_2$ I managed to get that $y = 2x_1+2(\sqrt{x}-x_1) = 2\sqrt{x}.$ Now this is just the square root function with a little shift upwards and looks as follows

[image]

And this is injective. Actually, it's even bijective, which seems to be in contradiction with the actual result that $h$ is not locally injective.

What might I be missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Your $2$-dimensional graph is wrong. You should be graphing $4x=y^2$. Just consider points with $y<0$ and you have a problem with writing $y=2\sqrt x$.

Nevertheless, the map $y\rightsquigarrow (4y^2,y)$ is an injective map. The problem comes from the fact that you have infinitely many values of $(x_1,x_2)$ with $x_1+x_2=y$ for any value of $y$. Just consider $x_2=c-x_1$. All the points $(x_1,c-x_1)$ map to the single point $(4c^2,2c)$.

Comment: Not sure I entirely follow the last statement. What do you exactly mean by $y\rightsquigarrow (4y^2,y)$?

Comment: I mean the function $\phi(y)=(4y^2,y)$. It is injective. The function $h=\phi\circ g$, where $g(x_1,x_2) = x_1+x_2$ is *not* injective, so the composition is not injective.